# Algorithm for splitting words randomly into defined length groups

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am writing a program (in JavaScript) which needs to randomly split a string (a single word) into groups of letters, with each groups length (character count) being either 2,3 or 4 characters long. For example, `australia` could return:

```
aus
tral
ia
```

or

```
au
str
alia
```

Currently I am doing it "manually", with if statements for each string length, eg:

```
if (word.length == 4){ //split
    sections.push(word.substr(0,2));
    sections.push(word.substr(2,4));
}

if (word.length == 5){ //either 2/3 or 3/2
    if (randomBetween(1,2) == 1){
        sections.push(word.substr(0,2));
        sections.push(word.substr(2,5));
    } else {
        sections.push(word.substr(0,3));
        sections.push(word.substr(3,5));
    }
}

etc...

// randomBetween(x,y) randomly returns one of the arguments
```

Does anyone have a more *algorithmic* solution?

Comment: How would you split "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", or "hi"?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't see any method to speed it up without making it more complicated. I assume you have code besides those if statements that chops up the string when length >= 6 or when length = 2 or 3.

Comment: Is there no access to random integers in javascript? Check the word length, then randomly select whether to cut off the first 2,3 or 4 letters (while making sure you ignore the cases that leave you with a suffix of length 1).

Comment: @elclanrs the words are of a set minimum and maximum length, so currently there would be an `if (length){...` for all words within that range

Comment: @eskimo what is the maximum length? You can handle anything 6 or more with a random method. 2, 3, and 5 are unique end cases. I have found a problem in your code. The use case for 4 can either result in 2 fragments of 2, or a single fragment of 4.

Comment: @Compass 5 is not a unique end case, since you can go 2-3 and 3-2.

Comment: @G.Bach I'm having a hard time describing the situation, to be honest. I guess 2, 3, 4, and 5 are unique "end" cases in that they will not have any other method calls after entering those loops.

Comment: @Compass the minimum length is 4 characters, the max is 12. I should have mentioned, for 4 it will always return 2/2 (I would probably check for length 4 and handle that separately first, as to not over complicate the rest of the algorithm)

Comment: @eskimo OK then. First, check if length == 4, then return 2/2. After that, the algorithm should run while the string's length >= 6, then you handle what happens when string's length is 2, 3, 4, or 5 after the while loop. That is about as compact as I can see it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a random length from 2 to 4 iteratively to form a list of groups. Handle the edge cases when the remaining string is too small to have all of these options available.

Note that not every possible combination will be chosen with uniform probability. I don't think there's a trivial way to do so efficiently.

I'll leave it to you to choose what happens if a word is passed in with a length less than 2.

```js
function randomlySplit(word) {
    var groups = [],
        tail = word;
    while (tail.length) {
        var availableLengths = [2, 3, 4];
        if (tail.length <= 3) availableLengths = [tail.length];
        if (tail.length === 4) availableLengths = [2];
        if (tail.length === 5) availableLengths = [2, 3];
        var length = availableLengths[(Math.random() * availableLengths.length) | 0];
        groups.push(tail.slice(0, length));
        tail = tail.slice(length);
    }
    return groups;
}
alert(randomlySplit("australia"));
```

You can see [this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1z4b20h/).

Answer (score 1):

I made a commented function for you, I hope it'll help.

```js
function randomlySplit(word) {
    var parts = [];
    // Loop as long as word exists
    while(word.length) {
        // Get an integer which is 2,3 or 4
        var partLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 2);
        // See if only 1 char would be left
        if(word.length - partLength === 1) {
            // Either add or subtract 1 to partLength
            if(partLength < 4) partLength++;
            else partLength--;
        }
        // No issue that partLength > word.length
        parts.push(word.substring(0,partLength));
        word = word.substring(partLength);
    }
    return parts;
}
alert(randomlySplit("australia"));
```